# Filter rows in df based on number of string occurances

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I’d like to filter rows in a df based on the condition that the row contains mentions of 2+ strings in a long list of strings. I’m having trouble specifying the number of occurrences. Here is my code so far:

```
brands = ["a", "b", "c"]
df[df.Column.str.contains('|'.join(brands), re.IGNORECASE, regex=True, na=False)]
```

Comment: df.column.str.isin(brands) will do the trick. The way to check for a list of elements is to use isin(name_of_list)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `count` instead of `contains`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':['ab','ABx','axy']})

df[df.Column.str.count('|'.join(brands), re.IGNORECASE, na=False)>=2]
```

Output:

```
  Column
0     ab
1    ABx
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the check. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test':['a','b','cat','dog']})
print (df)
df['check']= df['Test'].isin(['a','b','c'])
print (df)
```

This will result in:

```
  Test  check
0    a   True
1    b   True
2  cat  False
3  dog  False
```